# How to optimise a logic circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, homebrew-cpu

I have the following 15 sets of binary outputs:

```
A B C D E b c d e f
1         1
1           1
1             1
1               1
1                 1
  1         1
  1           1
  1             1
  1               1
    1         1
    1           1
    1             1
      1         1
      1           1
        1         1
```

I want to create a logic circuit that turns each 4-bit input value into a different 10-bit output row.  (There will be one 4 bit value unused, whose output I do not care about, as there are only 15 rows.)

The rows can be numbered in any order, provided there is an input that will generate each row.

How can I go about finding the optimal logic circuit and numbering scheme for the rows, to use the least gates?

Comment: Do you really mean outputs or do you mean inputs to your logic circuit? I think you may have 12 outputs and 15 inputs? What about the zeros?

Comment: Four bits of input (not shown) 15 outputs A-F and a-f.  Zeros not shown because they obscured the pattern in the output.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @DaveTweed this is not a homework question.  I am building a homebrewcpu and am looking for a faster alternative to having this table in an EPROM.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? You've offered us no clues about your level of skill in this area, and there's no way we're going to be able to give you a complete course in logic minimization in the space provided here. Also, you've provided no context around this problem, including the implementation technology you're using, or the timing constraints that you need to meet.

Comment: @DaveTweed So far, I've used a ROM in logisim.  I have a previous, working 8-bit homebrew CPU in logisim - I know how to use de Morgan's laws and Karnaugh maps, etc.  It's the fact that I can choose which input values maps to each output row, to minimise the logic, which is confusing me.

Comment: If the ROM works in logisim, why would you want or need anything else? If this is just a leaning exercise, then this **is** a homework problem as we define it, and that brings me back to my original comment.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, by that definition it's a homework problem.

Comment: So the question is find an ordering of the input space that minimizes the number of gates required to implement the 10 output functions so defined, that's kind of interesting, and sounds like a search problem to me (but don't they all?). Only 16! possible orderings, better get cranking :-).

Comment: @vicatcu Yes, that's exactly it, great wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you a couple of hints to get you started.

1. By neglecting to show the four bit inputs to the left of each row you have made your question somewhat confusing.
2. Since you have 10 outputs you will need to create 10 separate truth tables or Karnaugh maps.
3. After you have found a set of mimimized logic equations for each of the 10 outputs it will likely be a manual process determine where there are common logic terms that can be shared.
4. Trying to find the minimal overall logic solution will require iterative solving of the 10 truth tables with the different 4-bit input codes rotated among the rows.
5. There are tools available for solving truth tables or Karnaugh maps. Some are online and some are downloadable apps such as one I have seen in the Microsoft store.

Comment: I've failed to make clear that you can choose which four-bit input value generates each 10-bit output row.

Comment: @fadedbee - No "you" can choose. It's your design problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that some mappings of inputs to outputs may require less logic than others.  The 4-bit input value is part of the instruction coding, and can be arbitrary to reduce this logic.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, I will write some code to evaluate all 15! mappings.

Comment: @fadedbee - Exactly my point #4.

Comment: Logisim can do a big part of this. See its "Combinational analysis" window.